# Ubuntu Phone network selection

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, phone

hope everyone is well.

I recently bought the BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu phone recently, only had it 2 days and so far so good, well until now....

In the past all my phones you had the option to have your network selection automatic or manual. I can't for the life of me see how to have this on Ubuntu, it seems to be stuck on automatic I can't see any option how to select your network. Basically my problem is I live in a border area, and my phone keeps jumping onto a network from different country which ends up costing a fortune if you make / receive calls, messages or data.

Anyone know how to stop the phone changing network?

Thanks

Ps would love to show you a screen shot of this to help explain my situation, but I don't know how to take screen shots on this, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Cellular -> Carrier. There you can select the provider manually.

Comment: Thank you @Meles appreciate it. I seen that but I thought it was to do with the internet, was confused my different terminology, Cellular replaces Mobile and Carrier replaces network.